# MassTransit RabbitMQ get queue size

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I want the producer to not send new messages if the number of messages in the queue is greater than some threshold value.
To do this, I need to find out how many messages are currently in the queue.
Is there a way to do this using MassTransit framework?

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what you have done so far?

Comment: @Cerberton I haven't done anything yet. Right now I'm choosing which library to use to work with rabbit. If I can't get the queue size using MassTransit then I'll choose RabbitMQ.Client.

Answer (score 1):

MassTransit only uses the capabilities of a transport (which you haven't mentioned). Queue sizes and other measurements are usually parts of a management API of sorts. For example, an RMQ cluster or instance can be deployed without the management API (which is a plugin), so you can't get those measurements anyway.

For RMQ, you can use the management API or a wrapper, like [EasyNetQ management API](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/wiki/Management-API-Introduction), to fetch the metrics you need.

Comment: Or use [HareDu](https://github.com/ahives/HareDu2) to manage your broker, retrieve statistics, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I mentioned RabbitMQ in the title.
Using lib RabbitMQ.Client i can get queue size by calling method MessageCount(<queue_name>) of type IModel.
But I cant find anything like this in MassTransit lib.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question, but this is how I solved in case someone is still looking for a solution.

Note that I have running rabbitmq:**management** in docker

```
public static class QueueInfo
{
    public async static Task<RabbitMqQueueInfo> GetQueueInfo(string queueName)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var rabbitMqApiUrl = "http://localhost:15672/api";
        var rabbitMqVhost = "%2F";
        var rabbitMqApiUser = "guest";
        var rabbitMqApiPassword = "guest";
        var queueInfoUrl = $"{rabbitMqApiUrl}/queues/{rabbitMqVhost}/{queueName}";

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
            "Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{rabbitMqApiUser}:{rabbitMqApiPassword}")));

        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(queueInfoUrl);

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Failed to retrieve queue information for queue '{queueName}'.");
        }

        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var queueInfo = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<RabbitMqQueueInfo>(responseContent);

        if (queueInfo == null)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Failed to deserialize queue information for queue '{queueName}'.");
        }

        return queueInfo;
    }

    public class RabbitMqQueueInfo
    {
        public int messages { get; set; }
        public QueueStatus backing_queue_status { get; set; }
    }

    public class QueueStatus
    {
        public double avg_ack_egress_rate { get; set; }
        public double avg_ack_ingress_rate { get; set; }
        public double avg_egress_rate { get; set; }
        public double avg_ingress_rate { get; set; }
    }
}
```